# numpy logical.xor on a 2D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.x

I have a 2D numpy array with only `0` and `255` values (created from a black and white image) that i'd like to XOR with another similar 2D array.

The `dtype` of these arrays is `uint8` and their shapes are identical.

The only information and examples i've been able to find, so far, deal with 1D arrays.

Do I need to 'flatten' these 2D arrays before XOR'ing? If so, how is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.logical_xor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html) and [`numpy.bitwise_xor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html#numpy.bitwise_xor) will work for 2-D arrays, as will the operators `!=` and `^` (essentially logical and bitwise XOR, respectively).

**edit**: I just noticed in your title you are looking for logical XOR, but I will leave the bitwise info there for reference in case it's helpful.

**Setup**:

```
a = np.random.choice([0,255], (5,5))
b = np.random.choice([0,255], (5,5))

>>> a
array([[255, 255,   0, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0, 255,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0,   0]])
>>> b
array([[  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0,   0, 255,   0],
       [255,   0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0,   0, 255]])
```

**Logical XOR**:

```
>>> np.logical_xor(a,b)
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]])

# equivalently:
>>> a!=b
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]])
```

**Bitwise XOR**:

```
>>> np.bitwise_xor(a,b)
array([[255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0, 255,   0, 255]])

# equivalently:
>>> a^b
array([[255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255,   0, 255,   0, 255]])
```

Comment: It turns out, Bitwise XOR *was* what I was looking for ! :) I appreciate it!

Comment: is there a numpy function that returns the intersection of two 2D arrays?

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection in this case?

Comment: Returning an array that contains 255 values only where they exist (in the same location) in both array1 and array2.

Comment: in your case you could do something like `((a == 255) & (b == 255)) * 255`

Comment: I was assuming I'd need to iterate each array somehow. I'll give this a shot. Thanks again!